# Usage of "call A B" when A is long

Tags: sentence-construction

The original sentence that I used was as follows:

> For this reason, the region where the high-quality wireless link is supported from the ground base station id called the HQ region, and the region where the low-quality wireless link is supported from the ground base station id called the LQ region.

The sentence above gives the nuance that the terms "HQ area" and "LQ area" are the terms used typically in literature.
However, these two terms are only used in my writing.
Accordingly, in order to eliminate such a nuance, I decided to change the above sentence as follows.

> For this reason, we call the region where the high-quality wireless link is supported from the ground base station the HQ region and the region where the low-quality wireless link is supported from the ground base station the LQ region.

Is the changed sentence valid?
Since A is too long in the form of "call A B", I'm worried that my intentions will be misrepresented.
(Actually, I want to put "as" between A and B, but it is not idiomatic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your revised version is understandable. However, I think you've correctly pointed out that "A" is perhaps a bit too long for the reader to follow. But if this is for an academic paper, then you don't need to worry about the length of "A" (or that of the entire sentence). You could use commas, quotations, and dashes to aid readability.

> For this reason, we call the region where the high-quality wireless link is supported from the ground-base station the 'HQ region', and the region where the low-quality wireless link is supported from the ground-base station the 'LQ region'.

Similarly, you could use the n-dash:

> For this reason, we call the region where the high-quality wireless link is supported from the ground-base station – the HQ region, and the region where the low-quality wireless link is supported from the ground-base station – the LQ region.

Alternatively, you can use the form *"I will use the term B to refer to A"* instead of *"I will call A – B"*.

> From here on (or hereinafter), I will use the term 'HQ region' to refer to the region where the high-quality wireless link is supported from the ground-base station, and the term 'LQ region' to refer to the one where the low-quality wireless link is supported from the ground-base station.

Also, think about whether you need "ground-base[d?]" at all. I think the two relevant elements are "high-quality" and "low-quality".

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. Thanks to you, I found out about using n-dash. Actually 'ground base station' is the term I defined before. :-)